# grunt-usemin renames fonts with revision headers but doesn't update @font-face rule in css/sass

Tags: sass, font-face, grunt-usemin, yeoman-generator-angular

In [generator-angular](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular), [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/issues/221) is configured to revision static assets using [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev).

Grunt-filerev's sole responsibility [(I looked through the code)](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev/blob/master/tasks/filerev.js) is to rename the files. It then returns a summary object of the files renamed.

During the build process, grunt-usemin will then [rename references to the static files](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/blob/master/tasks/usemin.js#L128-L151) in your projects folders (in my project, I can see it happening with `img`s in html templates).

*Fonts*, however, get the revision hashes rename, but their references in my Sass files are not updated to reflect that - therefore, I get 404s on all my custom fonts.

I have already reached out [time](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular/issues/796) and [again](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin/pull/318) on issues in GitHub, but it looks like the good folks over there are respectfully busy with other business.

**The question is: is this a configuration error on my part which is easy to adjust, or a bug in grunt-usemin.**

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out?  I am faced with the same problem.

Comment: @Lowkase I manually added the fonts with the revision hashes to my scss file, and excluded them in bower.json so wire-dep won't append them again

Comment: @pilau Why are you trying to include the revved files in the SCSS file and not in the final, generated CSS file? Can you share your grunt usemin:css config?

Comment: @zbrukas it doesn't really matter, because it would work both ways. This is a half-assed workaround for a broken functionality.

Comment: @pilau I had a similar problem, turns out my Gruntfile had the following: ... assetsDirs: ['<%= config.dist %>','<%= config.dist>/images','<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts'] ... and I solved it by taking the fonts directory away, leaving just '<%= config.dist %>/styles'